# Excel match, sum and subtract from a single total

Tags: excel-formula

In the table below, IF C12:C21 match either D3 or e4, I want to sum the SWAG column per row and then subtract either D5 or E5 (based on the match) from the additive sum per column until I know that I've reached the value in either D5 or E5 (based on the team match)

[image: Table]

Comment: Where and how do you expect the result? If it's not an exact match, do you want the result @the SWAG row where the match is closest to, but smaller, or at the row where the sum equals or is greater than the team value? Also, do you have Office365?

Comment: In the committed column, and if there is not an exact match then skip. Yes, I have O365. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly what you mean, since you did not give an example of how the result you're looking for would look in given data. But this might be what you mean or at least usable to get to what you want:

```
=LET(swag,D12:D21,
     s,SEQUENCE(ROWS(swag)),
     r,MIN( 
            IFERROR(XMATCH(D5,SCAN(0,swag,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(OFFSET(b,,-1)=D4,a+b,a))),1),9^9), 
            IFERROR(XMATCH(E5,SCAN(0,swag,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(OFFSET(b,,-1)=E4,a+b,a))),1),9^9)),
IF(s=r,OFFSET(swag,,-1),""))
```

This uses the formula SCAN to conditionally sum the SWAG scores matching the correct team. Column F & G in the screenshot below demonstrate what SCAN does.

The MIN part of the formula compares the first matches equal to or greater than the values in row 4 to the scan value of it's team. If it results in no match it will give a high number as a result `9^9`, so it will not be the MIN value.
The min value is the nth row in the SCAN ranges or if both result in 9^9 it'll result in that high value.

Then, if a sequence to the number of rows of the swag range equals the min value it'll show the team name of that row. If both didn't match they will not have a match to the sequence and all rows remain blank.

[image]